# Mysql query performance with autocommit=0

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete more than 2 million records from a table by a mysql query (no joins).  The table has around 80 million records.

I used `set autocommit=0;` and it is taking long time to complete.  Will this be faster if I run the query with `autocommit=1`?

Comment: You did .. [*read* the autocommit documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_autocommit), right? It says exactly what it does. Then the question is merely about the correct use of transactions - as much as they are supported for the particular engine.  If an ACID engine is used then performance is limited to about 60 *write transactions* per second (within an order of such, anyway) due to needing to wait on a hardware *sync*. There is *no difference* for a single statement between an "autocommit" and a manual commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your table is **InnoDB**.  For those 2 million rows, it needs to keep track of the undo log entries for each modification. This builds up in the memory and will eventually go into disk.  That's why it's taking a long time. If you do it in chunks, that'll prevent it from going into disk and for MySQL to keep track of less undo log entries, making things more efficient.

The autocommit happens at the end of your query so it wouldn't do anything.

The best way to figure out what your chunk size should be is by experimenting. Something like

```sql
delete from table1 limit 1000;
```

Then keep doubling it until you come up with the best rows-deleted per time ratio.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are trying to run 2 million individual delete statements.

If you try bulk deletes using the primary key or ranges to delete 100-1000 records at a time it will be much much faster.

Examples:

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID > 0 AND ID < 1000;
```

OR

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4,5 .... 1000);
```

You can adjust the number of records to delete to your liking, increasing it quite a bit if you want. On high load production servers I usually run scripts with smaller ranges like this maybe 100 times before sleeping for a bit and then continuing with another loop.

I always have autocommit turned on for this type of thing. Managing a transaction to delete 2 million records would add a lot of overhead.

Also, please ensure the column you use for the bulk/range deleting is the either the primary key or has an index.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be any faster with changing value for autocommit variable. MySQL always build old image even if autocommit is true, because if user interrupts query then it must have old image to rollback.